# for loop inside a flask function -Internal server error

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am trying to print fibonacci series of a number using flask framework and jinja templates.
The following program is giving me a 505 Internal server error!
But when i comment the for loop inside the function,it gives me the correct result

fibonacciURL.py

```
from flask import Flask
from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader

app= Flask(__name__)

def fib(num):
    if num==1 or num==0:
        return num
    else:
        return fib(num-1)+fib(num-2)

@app.route('/fib/<number>')
def generate_fibonacci(number):

    env= Environment(loader=PackageLoader('Fibonacci','templates'))
    fibMap={}
   #for x in range(number):
   #      fibMap[i]=fib(i)


    for i in range(0,number):
       print 'Hello'
#pass

    template= env.get_template('table_template.html')
    return template.render(num=3,map={1:1,2:2,3:3})
#return 'wda'    

if __name__ =='__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

my table_template.html is

```
<table>
   {%for i in range(1,num)%}
    <tr>
    <td>{{i}}</td>
    <td>{{map[i]}}</td>
    </tr>
   {% endfor %}

</table>
```

Without the for loop,the page is showing the expected result

Comment: Turn debug mode on with `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)` . What does the error say?

Comment: I just had to try this out myself :) Nice idea for a [fib web app](https://gist.github.com/9e3fb6cbdc331972cc56)!

Comment: Can a moderator restore the content of this question? Not sure why it was removed! It was interesting :)

Comment: i will restore it myself after 2 weeks.I might be in trouble if it is restored now! So please don't restore it now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The route parameter `<number>` is given to you as a *string*, not an integer.

If you want Flask to give you a numeric value, tell it so in the route configuration:

```
@app.route('/fib/<int:number>')
```

See the [*Variable Rules* section](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#variable-rules) in the quickstart.